# CakePHP tags behavior header already sent error

Tags: cakephp, tags, tagging

Hi folks I'm trying to set up tagging in my CakePHP application. I've been using an article I found here: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/simple-tagging-behavior

The problem I'm having is when I add the line

```
var $actsAs = array('Tag'=>array('table_label'=>'tags', 'tags_label'=>'tag', 'separator'=>','));
```

to my project model.

I get the error:

```
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Library/WebServer/Documents/app/models/behaviors/tag.php:2) [CORE/cake/libs/controller/controller.php, line 746]
```

Is it a stupid syntax error I'm getting?

Jonesy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was white space above my open php tag in the behavoir model, removed it and the error is gone. It WAS a stupid mistake!